# Support of distribution functions in copula theory

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces

Suppose I have a distribution function $$C(u,v)$$ with domain $I^2$. Let us define the support of this function as the complement of the union of all open subsets of $I^2$ with C-measure zero.  Based on my understanding of the textbook I am reading (Nelsen's *An Introduction to Copulas*), the C-measure can be defined as $$ V_C(B) = C(u_2,v_2)-C(u_2,v_1)-C(u_1,v_2)+C(u_1,v_1) $$
I suspect that C-measure is a copula analogy to H-measure in probability distribution theory.

My questions are:

1. For a 2-dimensional distribution function H(x,y), is the H-measure the same thing as the H-volume, which is different than: $V_H(B) = H(x_2,y_2)-H(x_2,y_1)-H(x_1,y_2)+H(x_1,y_1)$?
2. Why is the support defined this way?  Why don't we just define it as the domain where $C(u,v)$ is not 0?  Does this make assumptions on the continuity of $C$? Does this exclude distributions which may be continuous in some intervals and have point masses in others?
3. Loosely, an open set is a set with no boundaries.  I can't seem to make the connection between this definition and open subsets of $I^2$.  Would it be correct to say that an open subset of $I^2$ is $(0.3,0.4)$, and another open subset of $I^2$ is $(0,1)$?  Again, why is this distribution function's support defined in terms of open subsets?

Thanks!